# how to Show the image in React Page as it showing object from Mongo db

Tags: reactjs, image-processing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThZph.png)I am facing an issue of rendering the image from API is converted in base 64 to image

```
  const [Cimage,setCimage] = useState([]);
```

```
useEffect(() => {
            async function getEntry(){
            try {
                const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/api/usernames")
                console.log(res.data[0].Coverimg);
                setEntries(res.data)
                
                setCimage(res.data[0].Coverimg.data);               
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
        getEntry();
        }, []);
```

```
const base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(Cimage)));
```

```
<img src = {`data:image/png;${base64String}`} alt="food" className="middle-img"/>
```

I am tring to converted  into in back to image, it should be preview on my sceen

Answer (score 0):

so, as the server is sending a JSON image, you need to convert JSON to Buffer with Int8Array

then that needs to be converted to Blob, and then create a URL object:

EDIT: use useEffect when fetching, that's what's giving that loop error

try it now:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

export default function CardData(){
const [data, setData] = useState(
    []
);


useEffect(() => {
   const url = 
   `http://localhost:5000/getDrawings/${localStorage.getItem("user")}`;
     Axios.get(url).then((res)=>{
    setData(res.data);
   }).catch(err=>console.log(err));
   }, []);
   return data;
}
```

Here is the example that I tried to solve your problem

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import CardData from "./CardData";

function Card(){

const cards = CardData();
try{const allCards = cards.map( function (data) {
    //let username = data.username;
    console.log("here!!!");
    const name = data.name;

    const blob = new Blob([Int8Array.from(data.img.data.data)], {type: data.img.contentType });

    const image = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    return( 
        <div className = "col-3">
            <div className = "adjust">
                <div className="image">
                    <img width="300" height="300" src={image}></img>
                </div>
                <div className="name">{name}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
})
return [allCards];}
catch(e){ return null;}
}

export default Card;
```